# Is the size_t data type safe to use for str.find()?

Tags: c++

I've been looking at code for the `find()` function for strings, and they store the result of that in a variable with data type size_t. However it is my understanding that size_t is an unsigned int, and if `find()` does not find the intended string, it returns -1. For example if I have

```
string s = "asdf";
size_t i = s.find("g")
cout << i;
```

It gives me 4294967295. However if I replace size_t with the int data type, it gives me -1. The strange thing is when I make a comparison like

```
string s = "asdf";
size_t i = s.find("g")
if (i == -1) { do_something; }
```

it works whether i is size_t or int. So which do I use? int or size_t?

Comment: Use `std::string::size_type` and `std::string::npos`

Answer (score 7):

Neither.

Under the [`std::string::find` documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find), it recommends that you use `string::size_type` and `string::npos` to detect not found in `find`:

```
 std::string::size_type i = s.find("g");
 if (i == std::string::npos) std::cout << "Not Found\n";
```

[Live example.](http://ideone.com/sLRKEw)

It shouldn't be surprising that `int` and `size_t` can be compared with -1 and work, they will have the bits, so when cast to do the comparison they will compare equally, you should however receive a warning such as:

> warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]

Comment: `size_type` should be `std::string::size_type` or better yet `auto`.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yeah, sorry, i was just about to fix that, for the purposes of answering the question with clarity, i think it is better to define the type so the OP can see it.

Comment: `std::string::size_type` is 100% `std::size_t`, guaranteed.

Comment: If I'm have `using namespace std;` do I have to type in string::npos?

Comment: @PCR You can type `s.npos`, though I can't promise your coworkers won't strangle you...

Comment: @T.C, probably, i didn't say it wasn't though. I still think using the documented `size_type` is a better idea.

Comment: You can also use something like `decltype(s)::size_type` or `decltype(s.size())` if you're in a generic context and don't know the type of `s`. Then again, you're probably better off with `auto` in this particular case

Comment: If `size_t` is `unsigned int` and shorter than `long`, then `i == -1` will promote both arguments to `long` (and always fail)

Comment: @Hurkyl Nope, that's not how the usual arithmetic conversions work. `int` + `unsigned int` always converts the `int` to `unsigned int`, never both to `long`.

Comment: @T.C. Ah you're right; it's the case that `size_t` has rank less than `int` that can cause problems.

Comment: @T.C.: the type used for `std::basic_string::size_type` is dictated by the specified `Allocator` for the class. It just happens that `std::string` and `std::wstring` use the default [`std::allocator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator), which does use `std::size_t` for its `size_type`. But a user could use `std::basic_string` directly with a custom `Allocator` that uses something other than `std::size_t`, eg: `typedef std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, CustomAllocator> MyString; MyString s;` then `s.find()` returns `CustomAllocator::size_type`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Then it's not `std::string::size_type`, is it?